# How to limit user for selecting options having min,max values in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want jQuery function. I have an **extra** named array which contains

1. min value
2. max value
3. options array (which contains some menu listing check boxes)

Now i have to limit the user to select min and max menu check box/check boxes inside **options array**. Note that **min** and **max** values are from **extra array** . 
For example. When user click on **addtocart()** function than it should show alert message that from this options array you have not choose min values or you can't choose more option from this options array because the max limit is 1.

Array format is

```
 "extras": [
        {
            "heading": "Bakery",
            "min": "1",
            "max": "1",
            "priority": null,
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "cheese",
                    "price": "45.00",
                    "priority": null,
                    "quantity": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "bread",
                    "price": "78.00",
                    "priority": null,
                    "quantity": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: It appears this is too much work to answer, because you did not provide your own code with what you have tried. You could try: Filling a dropdown with all the numbers from min to max. Or you could use a text input field, and validate on submission whether the values are between min and max.

Comment: Alright i will try and send you the code